# How to commit to Github through their API in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, git, github, github-api

I'm trying to commit a new file to a Github repo through a put request, but receive a 422 Unprocessable Entity Error.

Here is the the code with which I am trying to commit:

```
    $http.put('https://api.github.com/repos/<userName>/<repoName>/contents/main.js?access_token='+$scope.authObj.access_token, {
            path: '/main.js',
            message: 'testing',
            content: Base64.encode($scope.contents), 
            branch: 'master'
            }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(stuff);
    }).then(null, function(error) {
                console.error(error);
            });
```

Where `<userName>` is my Github name and `<repoName>` is the repo to which I am trying to commit.

Comment: http://mdswanson.com/blog/2011/07/23/digging-around-the-github-api-take-2.html  http://www.levibotelho.com/development/commit-a-file-with-the-github-api/

Comment: what is the message field and errors field of the response?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55548359/how-to-commit-files-larger-than-1mb-to-github-using-the-github-api-and-octokit-j might help